# Creating/deleting tables in db in running program on android

Tags: android, sqlite, multiple-tables

i am working on app that collects data from adroid phone and saves them in DB. And after 2 minutes, data from table in db are sent to server. This is working for me, but I need to delete data, that were already sent to server(cause they are useless anymore). So my idea is that every 2 minutes, i create new table, where i will save new data, and data from the old table will be send to server, and after the sending is finished, delete the old table. I am able to create new table only when the program starts, but i have no idea how to manage tables while the program is running. I would appreciate some small example of code, how can i manage that.

Thanks for answers

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just delete the rows you've sent from the current table after you've sent them?

Comment: why creating a new table? I bet each data object has a primary key which is also an attribute of the regarding data class. All you have to do is to remember the data objects. After sending to server take the ID's to prepare your delete statement.

Comment: Just send CREATE TABLE and DELETE TABLE sql commands to the db.  When you send them doesn't matter, they create and delete tables.  Although a better way to do it would be to send a row delete command to sql with no WHERE clause, that will cause it to delete all rows.

Comment: you can have some field like ISDeleted.Initially it will be 0.Once dats is sent to the server u can make it 1.Else u can delete the rows that have been sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for help, problem solved, when i send data to server, i can send all rows in one time, so creating new table was good idea for managing succesfull sending and wrong. Again, thanks for help anyway.